# Reading txt files within a jar

Tags: java, file, resources, embedded-resource

I've already looked at many other questions that are similar to mine, but unfortunately none of their answers have so far worked.

I have a Java project that looks like this:

```
MyProject/
    src/
        abc/
            MyClass.java
        xyz/
            file1.txt
            file2.txt
            ...
```

Essentially, I'm trying to read all of the txt files above in `MyClass.java`. This is what I'm currently doing:

```
File dir = new File("src/xyz/");
for (File child : dir.listFiles()) {
    ...
}
```

This works fine until I put everything into a JAR format, at which point `dir.listFiles()` returns `null` and the above no longer works. Is there anyway I can still read these txt files even when they are packed into a JAR? Also, I am using Eclipse if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access files on your classpath via the classloader.

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/xyz/file1.txt");
```

Then you would use the `InputStream` as usual. Note that I use absolute path, but relative to the current package works as well.

Since Java 6 it is also possible to list all the resources under a package quite easily:

```
 Enumeration urls = getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("xyz");
 urls.nextElement().openStream();
```

Comment: This requires that /xyz/file1.txt is included in the JAR. This may require modifying build properties or the equivalent.

Comment: Good answer.  Happy 1K.  :)

Comment: Thanks :) Also added a way to get all the resources under a package.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, although `Class` doesn't seem to have a `getResources` method.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway I can still read these txt files even when they are packed into a JAR?

Given you mean 'without knowing their names in advance' no.

OTOH you can include a resource at a known location in a Jar and list the possibles texts in that.  Path from root or class-path, one per line would work well.  Gain an URL to the resource using something like:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/path/to/the.resource");
```